# Total of percentages is not correct

Tags: java, math, rounding

I am distributing tokens but they are not all distributed. I have multiple percentages and get the amount of tokens to give for that percentage but they do not equal up to the total.

Example:

```
int tokens = 50;
double[] percentages = new double[] {0.3725, 0.219, 0.115, 0.2935};

int total = 0;
for(double d : percentages){
    int amount = (int) (tokens * d);
    total += amount;
}
```

The total is 47 though. I have also tried to round it with Math.round

```
for(double d : percentages){
    double rounded = Math.round(d * 100); 
    int amount = (int) (tokens * (rounded / 100));
    total += amount;
}
```

The total is 49

I can never seem to get 50, it is always below or above. I want to distribute these tokens are evenly as possible. If you can help please do!!

Comment: Try it with `BigDecimal` instead of `double`.  The `double` datatype is generally not very good for representing decimals  and doing arithmetic with them.

Comment: The cast to int leads to the loss of the numbers after the comma!

Comment: Yeah, OK, `int` is even worse than `double` for representing decimals.  Missed that!

Comment: The other hint: understand the concepts you are using. Don't just write down some source code blindly; **understand** what it means that java has these base types, and how the conversions between them work.

Comment: When you say tokens - are these discrete things that you are trying to allocate to match the percentages as closely as possible?

Answer (score 2):

Use `double` `total`. Using int leads to loss of decimal information

```
  double total = 0;
  for(double d : percentages){
      double amount = (tokens * d);
      total += amount;
  }
```

Comment: A token is generally a discrete thing, switching the count to a double does not really solve the problem.

Comment: @sidgate I know but I need to wait till 10 minutes after the question is asked before accepting. Also this hasn't actually really solved it now. The tokens need to be given but someone can't have like half a token hence why they were integers before. The amounts need to be whole numbers and need to equal 50

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is round down the percentages as you were originally (casting to int). Then look at how many tokens you have left over. These should be distributed to the cases that are furthest away from their true value.

In each case the error would be:

```
double error = (percentage * tokens) - (int)(percentage * tokens);
```

Sort your cases by error, and award the tokens to the cases with the largest error until you have given out all 50.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this works but I changed the total code to

```
total += income/1.025;
```

I think it works because while the loop doesn't display the age for 68 it still runs through one last time. So you'd have to undo the rate for retirement.

Comment: If you can figure out why that works and explain it clearly then that would help future readers of this question.